# Dropdown does not select if within Bootstrap Popover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Using jQuery v1.12.4, Bootstrap v3.3.7 and [Bootstrap-Select v1.10.0](https://github.com/silviomoreto/bootstrap-select).

I have 2  components within a popover. When the popover opens, I can click into the dropdowns but upon clicking an option, the selection does not change.

Please see this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/davidenco/uf6oohsu/).

### CSS

```
.flex { display: flex; }
```

---

### HTML

```
<div>
  <a role="button" class="btn btn-default" data-poc="#beds" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Bedrooms <span class="caret"></span></a>
  <div id="beds" class="hide">
    <div class="flex">
      <select name="minBeds" id="minBeds" class="selectpicker">
        <option>Min Beds</option>
        <option value="1">1 Bed</option>
        <option value="2">2 Bed</option>
        <option value="3">3 Bed</option>
        <option value="4">4 Bed</option>
        <option value="5">5 Bed</option>
      </select>
      <select name="maxBeds" id="maxBeds" class="selectpicker">
        <option>Max Beds</option>
        <option value="1">1 Bed</option>
        <option value="2">2 Bed</option>
        <option value="3">3 Bed</option>
        <option value="4">4 Bed</option>
        <option value="5">5 Bed</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

### JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.po').popover({
    animation: false,
    placement: 'bottom',
    html: true,
    content: function() {
      var poc = $(this).attr('data-poc');
      return $(poc).html();
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually there is some problem in working `popover` and `bootstrap-select`.
we can named it a bug. One solution is this :

```
$('.po').popover({
    content: $('#beds').html(),
    placement: 'bottom',
    html: true
}).on('shown.bs.popover', function() {
    $('.selectpicker2').selectpicker();
});
```

You can see the result in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uf6oohsu/2/), and the issue is discussed [here](https://github.com/silviomoreto/bootstrap-select/issues/383).